# Radio telescope alternative. Does a high resolution radio camera exists?

Tags: radio

I'm looking for an alternative to a radio telescope. Does a high resolution radio camera exists?

Comment: The best radio telescopes *are* diffraction limited radio-band camera. That is simply what such a critter looks like. To get higher resolution in a given band your only option is to go to larger apertures.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOFAR

Comment: dmeckee got it right: the better alternative to a radio telescope is a larger, more expensive radio telescope. That's very much like with cars... the better alternative to a slow , cheap car, is a larger, more expensive car.

Comment: I'm talking to someone who says he has a better alternative but he has not yet shared details i will post here if the device he has is interesting

Comment: Of course interferometry allows you to build a synthetic apperature. That's what @CountIblis' link is about: making your bigger and more expensive telescope out of a collection of small and cheap ones. That's an old game in radio astronomy.